# Someone has a website where I can exercise my vocabulary/grammar?

Tags: resources

I am looking for a website where I can exercise my grammar or my vocabulary knowledge, something like a textbook but online.

Quizzes such as sentence completion or vocabulary exams.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: There used to be an app called "La Grammatica italiana Treccani", but it seems that it doesn't exist anymore. An app called "Impiccato Treccani" may be useful to exercise vocabulary (but maybe it's not so useful for beginners, I don't now).